# manage null boolean with RxJava2 PublishSubject

Tags: android, mvp, rx-java2

I'm implementing the MVP design pattern. My presenter receives the new values from the view. I want to manage the state of a next button by automatically check if everything is valid when values are updated on the view.

In my form I have an optional part which is displayed only if the user select the correct option.
In this optional part I have a binary question. If the part is not displayed I need to set the value of the question to null on the Presenter side.
For example, the user select the option and the optional part is displayed. The user select the answer. Then the user change the option and the optional part is hidden. In that case I need to set the answer to the optional question to null, for the answer to not be already selected if the user display the optional part again.

To do so, I call a method on the Presenter with a null value instead of true/false.

Here is the code:

```
private final PublishSubject<Boolean> mObsOptionalAnswer = PublishSubject.create();

public MyPresenter(){
    // Combine all the values together to enable/disable the next button
    Observable.combineLatest(
        // ... other fields
        // I need this to return false if the optional part is 
        // displayed but nothing is selected
        mObsOptionalAnswer.map(this::isValid),
        (...) -> ...
    ).subscrible(enable ->{
        mView.enableBtn(enable);
    });     
}

public void myFunction(Boolean isSomething){
    // ... some code
    mObsOptionalAnswer.onNext(isSomething);
}

private boolean isValid(Boolean value){
    return value != null;
}
```

The problem is, since RxJava 2, `null` values are not allowed in the `onNext()` method.
So, how am I supposed to manage that?

Comment: You can use a 3-state enum instead of `Boolean`.

Comment: Maybe this is the cleanest solution but I wanted to avoid that as a Boolean has, in fact, 3 states already (true, false, null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to send a null value, you can use a wrapper. In this configuration, you send the wrapper, which isn't null even if the value itself is.

```
public class BooleanWrapper {

    public final Boolean value;

    public BooleanWrapper(Boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Your `PublishSubject<Boolean>` becomes a `PublishSubject<BooleanWrapper>` and you just have to create the wrapper and de-reference your Boolean when needed :

```
mObsOptionalAnswer.onNext(new BooleanWrapper(isSomething));
```

and

```
mObsOptionalAnswer.map(wrapper -> this.isValid(wrapper.value))
```

If you need to do that more than once in your code, you can create a generic wrapper (as described by [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@joshfein/handling-null-in-rxjava-2-0-10abd72afa0b)) :

```
public class Optional<M> {

    private final M optional;

    public Optional(@Nullable M optional) {
        this.optional = optional;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.optional == null;
    }

    public M get() {
        return optional;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a constante Boolean object

```
 public static final Boolean RESET_VALUE = new Boolean(false);
```

and you can `emit` this instead of emitting `null`. The receiver would have to check against this instance and behaving accordingly. Eg.

```
.subscrible(enable ->{
    if (enable != RESET_VALUE) {
        mView.enableBtn(enable);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I works but I get a warning from Android Studio: "`Unnecessary boxing 'new Boolean(false)`".

Comment: Are you still checking against the object reference? Btw you could use
`public static final Boolean RESET_VALUE = Boolean.valueOf(false);` . It will give you the same warning, but for your use case you need a new instance.

Comment: Yes I do. I just changed the code for `public static final Boolean RESET_VALUE = Boolean.FALSE;` as you suggested and it didn't work. What is the difference between `new Boolean(false)` and `Boolean.valueOf(false)`?

Comment: accordingly to the documentation is better to use the static factory method.      `Note: It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor.
     Unless a new instance is required, the static factory
     #valueOf(boolean) is generally a better choice. It is
      likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.`